# ASP.NET Core : AllowSynchronousIO = true per endpoint vs per server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Im using Net Core 3.1 web api and I need to set `AllowSynchronousIO = true`. I have seen 2 differents ways to do it:

Per Server (affects all endpoints)

```
services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
{
     options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
});
```

Or per Endpoint (inside a Controller's method):

```
var syncIOFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpBodyControlFeature>();
if (syncIOFeature != null)
{
    syncIOFeature.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
}
```

Question: if I set `AllowSynchronousIO=true` per server all my endpoints are Synchronous? Is there a performance issue to set `AllowSynchronousIO=true` per Server VS per Endpoint? Whitch is better? Or it's just the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Buffered Stream - Synchronous operations are disallowed in ASP.NET Core 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60984239/buffered-stream-synchronous-operations-are-disallowed-in-asp-net-core-3-0)

Comment: [AllowSynchronousIO disabled in all servers](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/7644)

Comment: Thanks for the links, I still with my doubt, maybe I'm missing something from them. I wanna know what is better option to use AllowSynchronousIO=true, used per Server or per Endpoint, and why. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the aspnet core team took an opinionated approach that could cause their consumers pain in changing the default behavior to AllowSynchronousIO = false, I would recommend the IHttpBodyControlFeature (per endpoint) methodology to conform more closely to Microsoft's recommendation by limiting the scope of overriding the default.  You can see a discussion around why they changed the default behavior [here](https://github.com/aspnet/ServerTests/issues/86#issuecomment-310823059) that explains it better than I can.

Additionally, I just ran into the issue using the global approach where we configured the KestrelServerOptions and it worked locally, but not when deployed because we additionally needed to configure the IISServerOptions.  There a post on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735133/asp-net-core-synchronous-operations-are-disallowed-call-writeasync-or-set-all).  This could be another reason to use the IHttpBodyControlFeature.